# Check for validation from different tables - joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am new to joomla. I am using RSDirectory Component. In this i have to customize validation. i have a file named rsdirectory.php which is located at: **administrator>components>com_resdirectory>helpers>rsdirectory.php**.

I have a table, table1. In which a unique code is stored. Now i want to fill a form using that code if exist then query will execute otherwise my validation code will be execute. i have done this successfully. Now i have an another table, table2 in which my data is storing when i am filling a form with unique code. i just want to check my unique code whether it is exist in table2 or not. if exist validation will execute.i want to use same function for both.

Here is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
public static function uniquestacksfield($value, $column,$column1,$id1=null, $id = null){
    // Get DBO.

    $column = 'uni_code';

    $db = JFactory::getDBO();



    $query = $db->getQuery(true)

            ->select($db->qn('id'))

            ->from($db->qn('#_table1', 'e'))


            ->where($db->qn($column) . ' = ' . $db->q($value));

    $db->setQuery($query);

    $entry = $db->loadObject();



    if ($id) {

        $query->where($db->qn('e.id') . ' = ' . $db->q($id));

    }

       $db->setQuery($query, 0, 1);

         return $db->loadResult();
```

/*------------------another query-----------------------*/

```
    $column1 = 'uni_code2';
        $db1 = JFactory::getDBO();     
       $query1 = $db1->getQuery(true)

            ->select($db1->qn('entry_id'))

            ->from($db1->qn('#_table2', 'c'))


            ->where($db1->qn($column1) . ' = ' . $db1->q($value));

    $db1->setQuery($query1);

    $entry1 = $db1->loadObject();



    if ($id1) {

        $query1->where($db1->qn('c_entry_id') . ' = ' . $db1->q($id1));

    }

       $db1->setQuery($query1, 0, 1);





     return $db1->loadResult();

}`
```

Comment: We aren't gonna write it for you, what have you tried and why didn't it work?

Comment: i've tried to write two queries within a single function of joomle.is it possible or not like that?

Comment: Can you give the link of that joomla extensions or can you upload and give the link? Its difficult to understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

***I think below code is may be use.you can try it now. it is not good explain more to your criteria***

```
 public static function uniquestacksfield($value, $column,$column1,$id1=null, $id = null){
    // Get DBO.
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $column = 'uni_code';   
    $column1 = 'uni_code2'; 

    if($column == 'uni_code') {    
        $query = $db->getQuery(true)
                ->select($db->qn('id'))
                ->from($db->qn('#_table1', 'e'))
                ->where($db->qn($column) . ' = ' . $db->q($value));
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $entry = $db->loadObject();     
        if ($id) {
          $query->where($db->qn('e.id') . ' = ' . $db->q($id));
        }       
    } else {
        $query = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->select($db->qn('entry_id'))
             ->from($db->qn('#_table2', 'c'))
            ->where($db->qn($column1) . ' = ' . $db->q($value));
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $entry = $db1->loadObject();
        if ($id) {
            $query->where($db->qn('c_entry_id') . ' = ' . $db->q($id1));
        }   
    }

        $db->setQuery($query, 0, 1);
        $item = $db->loadResult(); 
    return $item; 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, But i think you didn't understand what i want. Actually i have two tables.one from which i need to check my value that if it is exist in table or not. it should exist in that table. And in other table it shouldn't exist.